# ScrollMagic to simulate Uber's scroll effect

Tags: jquery, frontend, parallax, scrollmagic

As the title suggests, I am trying to simulate the scroll effect on Uber's website. I'm currently using the `ScrollMagic` library to try and achieve this and I *almost* have it, but need some help getting it the rest of the way.

See a demo of their scroll effect here: http://i.imgur.com/W3QLV7T.gif

You can see from the `gif` there are three sections. The sections on the right are scrolled independently, but the image of the cellphone stays fixed. The only time the cellphone scrolls along with the page is when the user scrolls past the first or third sections.

Find my [JSFiddle attempt here](https://jsfiddle.net/g5L4bctr/4/).

I am trying to "unpin" the image and end the trigger with the **Test 3** section and have it scroll up along with it, but I haven't had any success. My image falls under the bottom sections. How do I go about releasing the image at the correct scene to properly simulate the desired effect?

Comment: Please describe the effect instead of referencing off-site resources.

Comment: i would recommend using bootsraps scroll spy. This has the required libraries to do this: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your JSFiddle markup slightly, dried-up the JS, and added some lil CSS.

```js
(function($) {
  var imageSel = '#pinImg';
  var sectionsSel = '#start aside > section';  
  var pinStart, pinEnd, pinDuration;
  varsInit();

  var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
    addIndicators: true
  });

  var scenes = [
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerHook: 0.05,
      triggerElement: imageSel,
      duration: pinDuration
    })
    .setPin(imageSel)
  ];

  scenes = scenes.concat( createScene(sectionsSel) );

  controller.addScene( scenes );

  function varsInit() {
    // var afterMargin = 30;
    var sectionCount = 3;
    pinEnd = $( $(sectionsSel).get(sectionCount - 1) ).offset().top;
    // pinStart = $(imageSel).offset().top - afterMargin;
    pinDuration = pinEnd;
  }

  function createScene(sel) {
    var sceneList = [];
    $(sel).each(function(index, elem) {
      var focusClass = 'imageSel--'+ index;
      sceneList.push(
        new ScrollMagic.Scene({
          triggerHook: 0,
          triggerElement: elem,
          offset: -30,
          duration: ($(elem).outerHeight()+30)
        })
        .on('enter', function(e) {
          $(imageSel).addClass(focusClass);
        }) 
        .on('leave', function(e) {
          $(imageSel).removeClass(focusClass);
        })
      );
    });

    return sceneList;
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
/* Bootstrap Override  */
/* =================== */
.row {
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 0; 
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
} 
/* Bootstrap Override END */
/* ======================= */

.scrollmagic-pin-spacer {
  display: inline-block !important;
}

#start { min-height: 400vh; }
#start aside > section:first-child{ margin-top: 50%; }
#start aside > section .row { padding-bottom: 50%; }
#start aside > section:last-child .row { padding-bottom: 0; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 jumbotron">
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="start" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img id="pinImg" src="https://placehold.it/300x200">
    </div>
    <aside class="col-sm-6">
      <section>
        <div class="row">

          <div id="test1" class="col-sm-12 well">
            <h3>
              Test 1
            </h3>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
              in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section>
        <div class="row">
          <div id="test2" class="col-sm-12 well">
            <h3>
              Test 2
            </h3>
            <p>
              Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
              sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. 
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section>
        <div class="row">
          <div id="test3" class="col-sm-12 well">
            <h3>
              Test 3
            </h3>
            <p>
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
              survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </aside>
  </div>


  <section>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 jumbotron">
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 jumbotron">
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.js"></script>
```